# Writing shell script on Minix

Tags: bash, shell, minix

I'm totally new in writing shell scripts so I could use some help here.

I would like to write a script that when run with no parameters it just echo backs, and when it is given a data (.dat) file it displays the content of it.

Excuse me for my bad English,
R.

Comment: Here is the script you need: `cat`

Comment: Actually i need to write my own script. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This script, when run with no parameters it just echo backs and when a filename is passed as argument, it displays the content of it:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Explanation - We use'$#' to count number of arguments.
if ! [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
# Explanation - Zeroth argument '$0' is scriptname itself. Print it.
    cat "$0"
else
# Explanation - Print (cat) 1st argument.
    cat "$1"
fi
```

*NOTE: Since you've used 'minix' tag, I tested it on minix3. The script works well on minix as well as linux.*